# Why Can't browse Default website on IIS 7?

Tags: iis, windows-10, windows-services

I have an issue.
I installed IIS7 but i can't browse the simple Default website local host 80 port.

I already tried adding a new website with a simplet index.html file with simple text and different port, but is not possible.

I already give permissions to folders.

The message is Can not found this page HTTP ERROR 404

I have windows 10 pro OS

Any idea to solve this?

Comment: Try to configure the Default Web Site to run on another port. As you are using Windows 10, other applications can easily occupy port 80, and prevent IIS from working on that port.

Comment: @LexLi i already did that. I changed the port number to the Default website and another one that i created

Comment: What is the exact URL you are trying?

Comment: The next you might try are, 1) misconfigured site bindings which you might use Jexus Manager to diagnose, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html#background 2) read IIS log files to see what sub status of 404 you hit, https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0